# How to send a decimal number from python to arduino

Tags: python, arduino, binary

i am trying to send a decimal number from python to arduino, the problems is data is sent in an other type (i don't know which one maybe binary), so i did not get the desired response!
here is my arduino code

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char  k = Serial.read();
    if (k > 500) {
      analogWrite(10, 255);
      delay(1000);

    }
    if (150 < k < 500) {
      analogWrite(10, 128);
    }
    else if (k < 150) {
      analogWrite(10, 0);
      delay(1000);


    }
    Serial.print(k);
  }
}
```

& here is python code

```
import serial
import struct

arduinoData = serial.Serial('com3',9600)
data = 0

while(1==1):

    serialcmd = input("serial command: ")
arduinoData.write (struct.pack('>B',serialcmd))

data = arduinoData.readline()
print(data)
```

Comment: What kind of values are currently being printed. You must determine what format the data is being sent in.

Comment: nothing is printed on the python shell, only the serial command sentence waiting for the introduction of data!!

Comment: I think you need to use `arduinoData.write(struct.pack('>B',int(serialcmd)))` (and fix the indentation of the `whilw(1=1):` loop so it is inside of it). This change will convert the string value returned by `input()` into an integer value and send it to the arduino.

Comment: i've figured this out thank's

Comment: Was what I suggested helpful?

Comment: i am sorry but it wasn't sir, i used another mothod, thankyou!

Comment: in fact i am facing another problem if you could help, i want to change same prameters in arduino (variables "float"), how could i change it using pyserial, how could arduino knows that this tkinter button is to adjust this variable? i would be thankfull

Comment: You should ask a new question — it's not practical to address such involved follow-on queries in comments to another question.

Comment: okey, here is it's like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63233119/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-in-arduino-using-python-via-serial?noredirect=1#comment111815274_63233119